# Can't submit anything to facebook page from facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I now that this question was posted couple times but my problem is a little bit different. I try to submit for example event to my Page from Application.

1. I have private Profile on Facebook, Page and Application. Of course I'm admin of this page.
2. First thing I did was getting page `access_token`, so I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and in the URL I wrote `/me/accounts/`. Permission was set to `manage_pages`. I received `access_token` for my page.
3. Having `access_token` I connected my Application to the Page. So I made POST request to `/[PAGE_ID]/tabs/` with `app_id` as a parameter and setting `access_token` of the Page. Now it's connected, I've checked it.
4. Now I try to submit some content by my Application. For example `/[PAGE_ID]/events/` and passing parameters: `name` = `Sample event`, `start_time` = `2013-07-14T19:00:00-0700`. And of course with the Application's `access_token` which I got by typing in the browser: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&grant_type=client_credentials`. I got an error saying:
   {
     "error": {
       "type": "Exception", 
       "message": "You must be an admin of the specified page to perform the requested action.", 
       "code": 1373019
     }
   }
   I can post to this Page as a User but can't as an Application. My Application is of two types: Facebook Login and Facebook Tab. I've set permissions to `publish_action` and `manage_pages publish_stream create_event`.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved the problem. Maybe it can be helpful for others. I don't know for what reason are those permissions https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/permissions but the only thing I had to do was going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and changing application from Graph API Explorer to my app and generating new access_token for privilages I needed. I don't know why they moved such crucial thing as permissions to the testing tool.